# Hex Dump (byte array) with non standard Characters to int

Tags: python, hex, byte, arrays, hexdump

I am trying to convert a string of bytes/hex into int.

I've got a text log of data returned from a serial port reader, this is related to radiation.  The log records are like:

```
<20110805104053.421>
#00#00#64#05#00#00#00#00#00#00#3C#00#00#0D#0A
<20110805104055.421>
#00#00#5AÉ#00#00#00#00#00#00#3C#00#00#0D#0A
20110805104057.421>
#00#00#60÷#00#00#00#00#00#00#3C#00#00#0D#0A
<20110805104059.421>
#00#00#59#1C#00#00#00#00#00#00#3C#00#00#0D#0A
<20110805104101.421>
#00#00#5D#56#00#00#00#00#00#00#3C#00#00#0D#0A
<20110805104103.421>
#00#00#5D#09#00#00#00#00#00#00#3C#00#00#0D#0A
```

The format:

```
<TIMESTAMP (YYYY,MM,DD,HHMMSS.SS)>
DATA
```

With the data only the first 4 hashes (or so) are used in this case:

```
#00#00#5D#56
```

By formatting the string and using code:

```
>>> logdata = b'\x00\x00\x5D\x56'
>>> struct.unpack(">l", logdata)
(23894,)
>>> int(binascii.hexlify(bytearray(logdata)),16)
result: 23894
```

These numbers are expected, however sometimes the string is saved in special characters:

```
<20110805104055.421>
#00#00#5AÉ#00#00#00#00#00#00#3C#00#00#0D#0A
```

Using the same set method as above I convert the first 4 to:

```
 #00#00#5AÉ#00   or  ('\x00\x00\x5AÉ\x00')
```

Expected result is (from http://www.asciitohex.com/):

```
23040
```

My first result is:

```
5949696
```

Which is wrong, so I adjust the bytes to `'\x00\x00\x5AÉ'` and run again, this gives me:

```
23241
```

Which is very close to 23040, but not 23040???  This is pretty reproducible through a series of numbers, but not correct. When not using special characters my results are as expected and converted in asciitohex website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The É is hex C9.

0x5AC9 is 23241

If it were È (which is hex C8) you would get 23240.

[See http://www.pjb.com.au/comp/diacritics.html]

It looks like sometime, when the hex can be interpreted as a printable character like É, that character is output instead of the hex. In the case "#00#00#5AÉ#00" you don't want the string '\x00\x00\x5AÉ\x00' because that's 5 bytes not four (you can tell because there should be 11 remaining bytes after you grab what you want not 10) you only want '\x00\x00\x5AÉ'=5AC9.

Comment: so how does the website asciitohex.com interpret x00\x00\x5AÉ\x00 as 23040?  The problem is there is an "already converted" chart of the radiation values that I'm comparing to and 23040 is the result it gets as well

Comment: I'm not sure why that website tell you that. What exactly are you entering into the website form to get 23040?

Comment: adding to this, i'm going to also say that the "converted values" QA/QC is wrong and your method is right (some values #00#00Ÿñ#00 turn up as 0)